# Perform a specific action according to the run parameters in C++

Tags: c++

I have a program which reads a pmm image file and print the width , the height and the average color of the ppm image.This action is performed when the user gives as parameter something like that : `> main photo1.ppm`.When the user gives nothing then the programm ask for the file name to read. Is there any way to copy the image to a new image when the user gives as parameter this : `> main photo1.ppm -o newimage.ppm` ? Here is what I ve done so far :

```
int main() {
char fname[50];
cout << "Please enter the file name: ";

//Reads the file and print its data
}
```

Comment: Have you ever seen code that have arguments in the `main` function declaration? Something like `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or similar? Haven't you even wondered what that was all about? Also, it won't take much searching to find out how these are used with plenty of examples.

Comment: you should read this : http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/

Comment: That helped me thanks